# .stop() not preventing hover animation buildup

Tags: javascript, laravel, animation, hover, masonry

I have made a page for a client that uses masonry.js to load images into a grid. When you hover over the image a caption slidesUp and the image zooms in slightly. The problem im having is when you intitially load the page im experiencing very slow loading of the images and the zoom effect is jumpy and builds-up. Can you check-out the page to see if you have the same effect? If so I was wondering if it is the size of the images?? When I take the zoom effect off the page loads at normal speed.

here is the page

http://elephantegin.eu1.frbit.net/elephant-people

**Css:**

```
.grid-item {
    height: 180px;
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid_zoom {
    width: 105% !important;
}

.grid-item .grid_pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition-delay: 1s; /* delays for 1 second */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* for Safari & Chrome */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Here is the javascript I used.

```
$('.grid-item').hover(function () {
    var $item = $(this);
    var $img = $item.find('.grid_pic');
    var $callOut = $item.find('.grid_callout');

    $img.stop().toggleClass('grid_zoom');
    $callOut.stop().toggleClass('grid_slide_up');
});
```

Comment: Why are the images so big? 6667x3750 for each image is overkill. You should resize them and see how much that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the image size. I'd recommend to resize them to double the size of the wrapping divs (640x360), so they look decent on high resolution displays.

Note: calling jQuerys `stop()` method on the `$img` and `$callOut` elements has no effect. `stop()` will only stop animations triggered by jQuery, e.g. `animate()`, `fadeOut()` or `slideDown()`, but it wont stop CSS-transitions. However, removing the `grid_zoom` and `grid_slide_up` classes on mouseout will automatically reverse the animations as soon as you mouse out.